# Getting a 32-bit executable to run

Tags: apt, 20.04, package-management, 32-bit, executable

I'd like to install Ubuntu on a laptop that I use for work. The only thing stopping me is that I have a piece of (apparently) 32-bit software that I need for my work. According to the system requirements, it requires a 32-bit version of Linux to run, but I figured that getting it to run on a 64-bit system would be less of a hassle than installing a 32-bit system altogether. Perhaps I was wrong.

When I click on the executable, nothing happens. Trying to run it in the terminal returned the following message:

**error while loading shared libraries: libX11.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

When I tried to install the library mentioned above, I got this message:
**E: Unable to locate package libX11.so.6
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'libX11.so.6'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'libX11.so.6'**

I've already made sure that Multiarch support is active.

Is there any way to get it to run? Otherwise, is it worth seeking out and installing a 32-bit version of Ubuntu?

Thanks in advance and please go easy on me; I'm a total noob when it comes to Linux :)

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the 32-bit [package with mentioned library](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=focal&arch=any&mode=exactfilename&searchon=contents&keywords=libX11.so.6) by using commands below:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install libx11-6:i386
```

and then try to launch the application. If issue persists with another library - repeat the search process again and install more libraries.